# How to Combine 2 rows with different values in different column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to combine 2 rows with the same date but have different values ​​in different columns. like this:

```
tgl         qty_NEW MIO M3 125 CW-OTR  qty_NEW-SOUL-GT-125-OTR  
----------  -------------------------  -------------------------
2016-05-01  0                          0                        
2016-05-02  0                          0                        
2016-05-05  0                          0                        
2016-05-09  0                          0                        
2016-05-10  2                          0                        
2016-05-10  0                          1
```

There is the same 2016-05-10 with the values ​​are 2 - 0, and 0 - 1.

What I want is like this:

```
tgl         qty_NEW MIO M3 125 CW-OTR  qty_NEW-SOUL-GT-125-OTR  
----------  -------------------------  -------------------------
2016-05-01  0                          0                        
2016-05-02  0                          0                        
2016-05-05  0                          0                        
2016-05-09  0                          0                        
2016-05-10  2                          1
```

And the query I use is like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(m.tgl_fj) AS tgl , 
CASE brg.nama_brg WHEN 'NEW MIO M3 125 CW-OTR' THEN SUM(d.qty) ELSE '0' END AS 'qty_NEW MIO M3 125 CW-OTR' , 
CASE brg.nama_brg WHEN 'NEW-SOUL-GT-125-OTR' THEN SUM(d.qty) ELSE '0' END AS 'qty_NEW-SOUL-GT-125-OTR' 
FROM tb_mt_fj m
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_dt_fj_brg d
ON m.ucode_fj=d.ucode_fj
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_m_brg brg
ON d.ucode_brg=brg.ucode_brg
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_m_grp_brg grp
ON brg.ucode_grp_brg=grp.ucode_grp_brg
WHERE brg.ucode_grp_brg='11040000000089' AND MONTH(m.tgl_fj)=MONTH(NOW())
GROUP BY DATE(m.tgl_fj), brg.nama_brg
ORDER BY DATE(m.tgl_fj)
```

So, how to make the query result the same as I want?

Comment: In case of combination, is there only 1 non zero value? What if you have 3 rows for `2106-05-10` as `2 - 0`,`0 - 1` and `2 - 3`? What do you expect in output then?

Comment: @Utsav if 3 rows, then there are 3 values `2-0-0`,`0-1-0`,`0-0-3` and the output is `2-1-3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should do it

```
select tgl, sum(qty_NEW MIO M3 125 CW-OTR) as `left`, sum(qty_NEW-SOUL-GT-125-OTR) as `right` from `table` group by tgl
```